# How can I ensure that file has been transfered completely onto destination remote server using oracle DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE() utility?

Tags: oracle, groovy

Below is my groovy code which transfer and import the oracle .dmp file from my local to remote (rds instance) but the problem is before DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER transfer the file on to dest. server my impdp command executes which through exceptions.

I want to check in my code whether the DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER has transferred the file completely so i can proceed to impdp command.

Is there any way to check the status of transferred file before importing it.

```
sql.call("""BEGIN
  DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE(
    source_directory_object       => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
    source_file_name              => '"""+schema+""".dmp',
    destination_directory_object  => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
    destination_file_name         => '"""+schema+""".dmp',
    destination_database          => 'to_rds'
  );
END;""")

println("Dump file has been transfered to destination server successfully...")

DropUser(rDbUrl,rUser,rPassword,driver,schema)

def impCmp = """cmd /c impdp """+rUser+"""/"""+rPassword+"""@db-m3-medium.coplvukvijdo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ORCL DUMPFILE="""+schema+""".dmp DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR full=y"""
proc=impCmp.execute()
proc.waitFor()
println("Dump file has been imported on to destination server successfully...")
```

Comment: The documentation `http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_ftran.htm#ARPLS66384` states that "To monitor the progress of a long file transfer, query the V$SESSION_LONGOPS dynamic performance view." So this could be a possible approach.